# How is the "Moral High Ground" Mission Card intended to work?

Tags: the-agents

The text of "Moral High Ground" goes something like "For each Free Agent revealed in your hand", and is worth 1 IP per reveal.  This brought up some debate on exactly what and WHEN the reveal was qualified.  The first player to use it played his Free Agents, then tried to claim the points. I argued that because he had played them, when the mission was evaluated at his turn's end, he no longer hand the Agent "in hand."  Also, with a name like "Moral High Ground" actually playing the Agent seemed against the spirit of the card.

Later on, another player got this Mission and tried the tactic of revealing a Free Agent, then playing it.  His argument was that when evaluating the Mission, he had revealed the Agent during his turn, so it should apply.  That seems like splitting hairs to me though.

So what is the correct interpretation of this Mission Card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missions score at the end of your turn, after taking actions such as playing agents.**

Although **reveal** isn't defined in the [rule book](http://thoughtprocess.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/rules_08_PnP1.pdf), they do use it in the context of revealing cards from your hand. You cannot reveal an agent unless it is in your hand.

> **Moral High Ground:** {1} for each killing or turning agent you reveal from your hand.

The **Turn Sequence** section states:

> **Turn Sequence** - On each player’s turn, they have to perform 2 actions. Players can select from any combination of the following (including performing the same action twice);
>
> 1. Playing an Agent [...]
> 2. Re-activating a Command [...]
> 3. Buying an Agent or Mission: [...]
> 4. Trade in a Mission [...]
>
> At the end of their turn, the player whose turn it is collects their intel points from their Factions and Missions. Players collect intel points from their Factions and Missions each turn as long as the data-tokens remain complete on their Factions and **the conditions of the Missions remain fulfilled.**

Although the conditions of the mission don't say when they must be fulfilled, I would argue that all the other mission conditions require checking at the end of the turn, so should this one. (You might also argue that to fulfill the conditions, you must continue to reveal the killing/turning agents until the end of turn, or you stop fulfilling the conditions. I.e. You are no longer **revealing** them.) Scoring of Missions also repeats the conditions must be fulfilled at the end of turn:

> **Scoring Intel Points** - Intel points are awarded:
>
> 1. to players who have completed arrows facing them in their Factions at the end of their turn,
> 2. when the **condition of a Mission is fulfilled** at the end of their turn,
> 3. to players towards whom the points are directed when a Free Agent is played.

Comment: Although the interpretation is unchanged, this card must have been changed in the official print version from the PnP. The version of Moral High Ground I have awards points for every "Free Agent" revealed.